# How to filter DATESBETWEEN based on column value (to calculate number of business days in a month)

Tags: ssas, tabular, dax

Working on an SSAS Tabular project in Visual Studio 2010;

I'm trying to create a measure that calculates the total number of business days in a month:

I have `Month Start Date` and `Month End Date` measures, and `Date` and `Is Business Day` columns.

I can create a `Total Business Days` measure with `COUNTROWS(FILTER(Dates,Dates[Is Business Day]=TRUE()))`. That gives me the number of business days in the context, but I want the number of business days for the current month.

I've tried various combinations of `FILTER`, `COUNT`, `COUNTX`, `COUNTROWS`, `DATESBETWEEN`, and `CALCULATE` without success.

What I want is a count of days between two dates, where the column `[Is Business Day]` is true, but I can't seem to get the right combination of filtering.

I would guess I filter the Dates table the way I do for the `Total Business Days` measure, but `FILTER` returns a table and `COUNTROWS` expects a single column - is there a way to get single column from a `FILTER` result?

Comment: If your date dimension is hierarchical, what about give a try to the `Children` function?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one thought...

First, create a calculated column called MonthKey (if you don't have it already):

```
=YEAR([Date]) * 100 + MONTH([Date])
```

Then create another calculated column called IsCurrentMonth

```
=IF(YEAR(TODAY()) * 100 + MONTH(TODAY()) = [MonthKey], 1, 0)
```

Then you can create your calculated measure as

```
COUNTROWS(FILTER(Dates,Dates[IsCurrentMonth] = 1))
```

Would that do what you need?